# What does the buffer.append do it this piece of code?

Tags: android, html, jsoup, buffer, element

I am using Jsoup to print off HTMl to a mobile app and i know this is the code that is printing the meta data but i want to know exactly what buffer.append is doing?

```
          StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

         // Get meta info
            Elements metaElems = doc.select("meta");
            buffer.append("META DATA\r\n");
            for (Element metaElem : metaElems) {
                String name = metaElem.attr("name");
                String content = metaElem.attr("content");
                buffer.append("name ["+name+"] - content ["+content+"] \r\n");
            }
```

Comment: What is buffer? String? StringBuffer? Bufferedreader? ...

Comment: StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

Comment: My guess is that it appends something to the buffer. Most likely the string that was passed in as a parameter. I'm not sure which part is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Always somehow include the specific Class you're talking about with your code/question. To a reader, the `buffer` variable could be anything.

Judging from the context of your code you're probably talking about an instance of the java class `StringBuffer`. Read more about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html).
In a nutshell, it's like a `String`, just *mutable*, which means you can change its content after it has been instantiated like your code snippet is doing with `.append(..)`. 
Just call `buffer.toString()` once you're done with appending things to it and continue using the String Object that the buffer will return.